# Processing each row by a function that adds multiple columns to a data frame

Tags: r

I have a list of location and dates in the airports data frame and need to extend it by weather data (24 cols), where each of the rows has to be passed through a `getWeatherForDate` function.

```
Location Date
AMS  2017-08-01
AMS  2017-08-02
EDI  2017-08-02
...
```

As a result I would like to have a **data frame** where these additional **24 columns** that are returned by the function are joined with my data frame.
Each row has to be processed by something like:

`getWeatherForDate(aiports$Location, aiports$Date, opt_all_columns = TRUE)`

A desired output:

```
Location Date Min_temp Max_temp Max_humidity ...
AMS  2017-08-01 21 30 88
AMS  2017-08-02 23 28 87
EDI  2017-08-02 12 18 77
...
```

What's a smart and optimal way of doing it? `by`? `lapply`? `foreach`?

Comment: If it's each of the rows, then `lapply` won't do it, since it processes `data.frame` columns. Maybe `apply(airport, 1, FUN)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it using `by` function:

```
output <- do.call("rbind", by(aiports, 1:nrow(aiports), function(row) cbind(row, getWeatherForDate(row$Location, row$Date))))
```